# multinomial logistic regression modelling

Tags: regression, logistic, dataset

I want to find the determinants of choice of delivery by expecting mothers in India where we have 3 categories:

- home
- public health facility
- and private hospital

For each category, I know the total number of deliveries and aggregated determinants such as female literacy percentage, percentage of villages without health facility, percentage of households living in lowest quintile income, etc.

What is the most reasonable model to predict the delivery based on the determinants?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the application of Bayes formula. For each of 3 categories, you have total number which can be labeled as $n_i$ for $i\in\{1, 2, 3\}$. Thus, you can use the prior as 
$$
P(C=i) = \frac{n_i}{\sum_{j=1}^3 n_j}
$$
The percentages of determinants, you can interpret as likelihood $P(X_k|C=i)$. For example, the probability of living in a village conditioned by delivery at home. The index $k=1,\dots m$ where $m$ is total number of determinants. Thus, for each category, we will have $m$ likelihoods.

For that purpose, you can use naive Bayesian classifier:
$$
P(C=i|X_1, X_2, \dots, X_m) = \frac{P(C=i) \prod_{k=1}^{m} P(X_k|C=i)}{z}
$$
where 
$$
z = \sum_{i=1}^{3}\left(P(C=i) \prod_{k=1}^{m} P(X_k|C=i)\right)
$$